# cakephp redirects incorrect path

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a login form (login.ctp) in my Members View. But when I give the url as /login, than instead of showing the login of Members view, its showing login page of users view.

/Views/login.ctp file

```
<div class="members form">
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Member'); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Please enter your username and password'); ?></legend>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');
?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Login')); ?>
</div>
```

App controller file

```
class AppController extends Controller {
//...

public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'members', 'action' => 'home'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'members', 'action' => 'index')
    )
);

public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
}
//...
}
```

My routes.php file

```
 Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'members', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/login', array('controller' => 'members', 'action' => 'login'));
```

I have cleared all the cookies. Where is the mistake?

One more thing, I have even tried deleting user controllers, but if I delete user controllers I get the following error...

Error: UsersController could not be found.

This is my login function from MembersController.php

```
         public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }
}
```

//code in member model.

```
class Member extends AppModel {

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
public $validate = array(
    'firstname' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'lastname' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'email' => array(
            'rule' => array('email'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'age' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'address' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'phone' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'created_on' => array(
        'datetime' => array(
            'rule' => array('datetime'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
);

function beforeSave() {
  if(isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password']))
    $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = Security::hash($this->data[$this->alias]['password'], null, true);
  return true;
}
}
```

Comment: when site is load you want to display members/login form by default. m i right ?

Comment: nope , i want to display index file itself, but when i change the path to /login, login file must be displayed

Comment: add login action in beforeFilter and try.

Comment: Are you still using the User model or do you only have a Member model?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Tested Code and process

**AppController Code**

```
<?php
class AppController extends Controller
{
    public $components = array
    (
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array
        (
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'members', 'action' => 'home'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'members', 'action' => 'index')
        )
    );

    public function beforeFilter()
    {
        $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
        $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password');
        $this->Auth->userModel = 'Member';
    }
}
```

all of your code is working fine all you need to do is just set `Auth->userModel` to `Member`.

**MemberController**

```
<?php
class MembersController extends AppController
{

    var $name = 'Members';

    function beforeFilter()
    {
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }

}
?>
```

And in Member controller define `beforeFilter as above.`

Comment: also need to add loginAction in Auth declaration.

Comment: your code is working at my side just need to update your app_controller beforeFilter and need to add $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password');
  $this->Auth->userModel = 'Member'; this code in there...

Comment: have u declared before Filter in member controller as described in answer.?

Comment: Do you want me to delete the users model ??

Comment: can i see code inside member model.? and for checking rename user model so you can have more idea..and set debug to 2 in core.php

Comment: renaming user model is not solving my problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23358/discussion-between-pavan-k-and-dipesh-parmar)

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your components array to this:

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'members', 'action' => 'home'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'members', 'action' => 'index'),
        'Form' => array(
            'userModel' => 'Member'
        ),
    )
);
```

Or try this in beforeFilter():

```
// Pass settings in using 'all'
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    AuthComponent::ALL => array('userModel' => 'Member'),
    'Form',
    'Basic'
);
```

Comment: I don't think so, if you just want to switch out the User class for the Member class, you just need set the 'userModel' to 'Member' for the AuthComponent.  Another way to do this is described at: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers (see edited answer)

Comment: i have done it bro but i am still being redirected to users/login page

Comment: Do you want me to delete the users model ??