# Auth component in cakephp supports only UsersController?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I might hav askd question related to this earlier but not satisfied by answers and no answer is working.....My doubt is little different , i have two controllers
1.UsersController.
2.MembersController.

My doubt is the Auth component is working wonders for UsersControllers, but the Auth is not working for MembersController. In simple terms whenever i try to use Auth component for my MembersController, instead of redirecting to Members view. It is displaying UsersController pages....And when i delete the UsersController i get below error...

Error: UsersController could not be found.

Is there any connection between Auth and Users. How to set Auth component for my MembersController......

This is how i am using it....

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'members', 'action' => 'home'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'members', 'action' => 'index')
    )
);

public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
}
```

Comment: why both UsersController and MembersController? arent they one and the same? Or are you trying to only use MembersController? Why did you not specify the cakephp version? that is crucial information for a question like that.

Comment: I am only trying to use MembersController..(members is a table in my db and i am using that )....my version is of cake is 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your App Controller

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array(
        'Auth' => array(
            'authorize' => 'actions',
            'actionPath' => 'controllers/',
            'loginAction' => array(
                'controller' => 'members',
                'action' => 'login',
                'plugin' => false,
               'admin' => false,
                ),
             ),
         );
}
```

Comment: Try clearing all cache in tmp directory and try again in private browsing mode

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516063/cakephp-redirects-incorrect-path    This is my earlier question, i hav mentioned all codes in it.....U can hav a look

Comment: Check routes path in app/config.php

Comment: That's really strange Dipesh covered everything.. Have you baked your project? and whats the table name in database? Try using loadModel to forcefully load members table

Comment: Even i am surprised why the hell i am getting error i used            cake bake all.

Comment: again i m telling you u forget $this->Auth->userModel = 'Member'; in appcontroller beforeFilter function..

Comment: I had the same problem as "php geek". The "/login" keeps on redirecting to the "Users controller", and not to my custom-made controller. It has nothing to do with routes.php